# IP Filtering using grepcidr / bash

Tags: bash

Trying to filter IP' list and reject the IP's from the list "service_ip_list"
For some strange reason, grepcidr searches only in first 3 IP's from list "service_ip_list" and ignores the rest, any one know how to fix this ?

```
ip_filtering() { service_ip_list=("192.168.1.1" "192.168.1.2" "192.168.1.8" "192.168.1.80" "192.168.1.20" "192.168.1.200")
    grepcidr "$service_ip_list" <(echo "$1") >/dev/null && \
        echo "$1 is a Service IP" || \
        echo $1 >> live_ser_list
}

for i in 192.168.1.{1..254}
 do
 ip_filtering $i & disown
 done
```

Comment: I suppose you use the array elements as `"${service_ip_list[@]}"`, in your example though, you are just using it in a variable context

Comment: no, I'f I'm doing it it gives  me : 192.168.1.2: No such file or directory so on , for each IP

Comment: I thought it was understood, I meant something like `<(printf "%s" "${service_ip_list[@]}")` instead of the `echo` block you had

Comment: No, it is not working,  grepcidr expects the ips to be in a file, don't accepts just an argument, , using <(printf "%s" "${service_ip_list[@]}")  works in terms of no error are coming up, but then it stops filtering even first 3 IP's,

Answer (score 0):

It's not grepcidr, and in case of matching ip's in Networks list, like 10.0.0.0/24 you may use/need grepcidr,
but if you need to filter IP's by rejecting the ones from the array, the simple solution would be:

```
    #your array
    declare -a service_ip_list=("192.168.1.1" "192.168.1.2" "192.168.1.8" "192.168.1.80" "192.168.1.20" "192.168.1.200")
    ip_filtering () {
    #this will match your IP to the IP's from the array    
    if [[ " ${service_ip_list[@]} " =~ " ${1} " ]]; then
        #if found in array
        echo "$1 is a Service IP"
    else
        #if not found in array
        echo $1 >> live_ser_list
    fi
    }
    # your IP source
    for i in 192.168.1.{1..254}
     do
     ip_filtering $i & disown
     done
```